# How to change view dynamically based on something in CodeIgniter3?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I have a CodeIgniter 3 project where I have a user profile page with different sections, and I want to load different views based on the active section. Currently, I have JavaScript code that changes the active class of each section when clicked.

The view:

```
<? defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed'); ?>
<div class="profile-container">
  <div class="profile-sections">
    <!-- User Profile section -->
    <section class="active">
      <i class="section-icon fas fa-user"></i>
      <span class="section-title">User Profile</span>
    </section>

    <!-- Payment Methods section -->
    <section>
      <i class="section-icon fas fa-credit-card"></i>
      <span class="section-title">Payment Methods</span>
    </section>

    <!-- History section -->
    <section>
      <i class="section-icon fas fa-history"></i>
      <span class="section-title">History</span>
    </section>

    <!-- Bonuses section -->
    <section>
      <i class="section-icon fas fa-gift"></i>
      <span class="section-title">Bonuses</span>
    </section>

    <!-- Support section -->
    <section>
      <i class="section-icon fas fa-headset"></i>
      <span class="section-title">Support</span>
    </section>
  </div>

  <!--TODO: Change content dynamically here-->
  <div class="section-content">
    <? $this->load->view("user_profile"); ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  //Get all the sections
  const SECTIONS = document.querySelectorAll("section");

  //For each section add a click event that changes the active class accordingly
  SECTIONS.forEach((section) => {
    section.addEventListener("click", function () {
      SECTIONS.forEach((section) => section.classList.remove("active"));
      this.classList.add("active");
    });
  });
});
```

How can I load different views based on the active section without using JavaScript and without changing the URI in CodeIgniter 3?

**EDIT:**
The controller is loading the view, but I want to change which view is displayed dynamically:

```
<?
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Profile extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        if(!$this->session->has_userdata('logged_in'))
            redirect(base_url());

        $data = array(
            'title' => 'Profile',
            'css' => array(base_url('resources/css/style.css'), base_url('resources/css/profile.css')),
            'script' => base_url('resources/scripts/profile-sections.js')
        );

        $this->load->view('commons/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('commons/navbar');
        $this->load->view('profile');
        $this->load->view('commons/footer');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Selecting which view to load should be done with your controller, not with the view itself.

Comment: You have to do it from controller's end as @AdamWinter mentioned in above comment.